# How to stop function replacing itself with Variant result

Tags: vba, excel

The function below is part of an Excel Add-in to send orders to a broker. I believe access to the inner workings of the Add-in is unavailable.

When the formula and arguments are entered into a spreadsheet cell and executed (i.e. the order is sent), the contents of the cell are replaced by a variable of type Variant (e.g. "Formula sent", "WORKING", and presumably other possibilities).

How can the output be best analysed programmatically when the function's response is "Variant"? Also, how to prevent replacement of the formula by its result?

```
Function orderSend(Optional account As String = vbNullString, Optional symbol As String = vbNullString, Optional side As String = vbNullString, Optional price As Currency = 0, Optional orderQty As Currency = 0, Optional orderType As String = vbNullString, Optional timeInForce As String = vbNullString, Optional expiryTime As String = vbNullString, Optional stopPrice As Currency = 0) As Variant
    ' Really Optional: price expiryTime stopPrice
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        orderSend = tradingAddInFunctions.orderSend(Application.Caller, account, symbol, side, price, orderQty, orderType, timeInForce, expiryTime, stopPrice)
        Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    orderSend = Err.Source & ": " & Err.Description
End Function
```

Comment: When you type the formula, it shouldn't be replaced with the actual value. It will display the result but will not alter the actual formula written in the cell. As for analyzing the result, you can do that inside the function. Since it is a variant type, you can use various test available like *IsArray*, *IsError* etc. for VBA

Comment: Thanks, okay we will classify the output. However, the formula is certainly being overridden by the result, presumably because the Add-in wants to ensure that the formula isn't executed repeatedly.

Comment: If it is the add-in that's causing it then there is no way for us to determine how to stop it without the actual add-in code. Also, it would be too cumbersome to do and would be out SO's scope. Based on the function you posted there is no way that it would replace the formula into value.